# What does the free body diagram for mass 1 look like?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

In this situation:

[image: free body diagram of box on box]

Enough tension is applied towards the right on $m_2$ so that $m_1$ starts sliding backwards.

I am confused about what the free body diagram for $m_1$ looks like.

Here is my attempt: 
[image]

The net force in the $x$ direction on $m_1$ is negative, right? Otherwise the box wouldn't be sliding backwards.

Comment: Are you in the top box's frame or the frame which is stationary with respect to the ground?

Comment: The way I drew it I think it's the reference framework with respect to stationary ground.

Comment: Because sliding of m1 implies net acceleration of 0, right?

Comment: Oh ok, but actually I think you are viewing the situation from the bottom box's frame and you just don't know it. In the ground's frame there is no leftward force on the top box (correct me if I'm wrong). The top box ought to move to the right, just not as fast as the bottom box.

Comment: I think I see what the source of confusion is. When the question says sliding backwards, it means sliding backwards relative to the bottom box (or, in other words, sliding backwards in the frame of the bottom box). It does not mean that the top box is moving backwards in the ground's frame. In fact, the top box will still be moving forward in the ground's frame. You are correct that if the top box were to be sliding backwards in the ground's frame, there must be a leftward force on it. This was a badly worded question.

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs - I just changed my FBD above based on everyone's comments above. Am I closer to a correct diagram?

Comment: Everything is fine except you included too much. The free body diagram for $m_1$ should only include forces on $m_1$, not the force on $m_2$ or the net force on the whole system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good question that addresses a common misconception.

Short answer: 
The box $m_1$ does NOT slide backward. The friction force in the $+x$ direction causes the box 1 to slide forward, but not fast enough to keep up with the larger box 2. There are *no* backward force in the x-direction - there is only the forward friction force in the +x direction.

Be careful with your free body diagram. You should only show the forces applied **directly** on box 1. The tension force is applied on a different body (e.g. Box 2), so it plays no role in describing the motion of Box 1.